# Constructing congruent triangles and give a proof

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

I need to construct from a given triangle $\Delta ABC$ a congruent triangle $\Delta XYZ$ and I know how to do this if I'm allowed to "measure an angle with a compass" and carry that measurement over to another point--but I need to do this construction without such an ability.

Now I actually have, I think, done the construction but I cannot complete the proof.  Here's what I've done so far.

For a given triangle, select a random point $X$.  Below I will construct a point $Y$ so that $AB=XY$.

Draw a circle centered at $A$ passing through $X$ and a circle centered at $X$ passing through $A$, and call one of the intersections of these $D$.  Form $\angle ADX$.  Draw a circle centered at $A$ passing through $B$ and label the intersection with $\overrightarrow{DA}$ that is farthest from $D$ the point $E$.    Draw the circle centered at $D$ passign through $E$ and label the intersection with $\overrightarrow{DX}$ the point $F$.  I can prove that $XF=AB$.

I can repeat the process to get a point on $\overrightarrow{DX}$ so that the length is the same as $AC$ too.  Call the point $Z$

I believe that if I form the circle centered at $X$ through $F$ and the circle centered at $F$ through $X$ and label an intersection $Y$, then $\Delta XYZ \cong \Delta ABC$.  However, I can only use SSS or SAS to prove this and I only see how to prove that $XY=AB$ and $XZ=AC$.  I don't have any way that I know of to prove that angles are congruent except by proving triangles are congruent and using CPCTC.  That leaves proving $YZ=BC$ which I'm struggling to do.

Many thanks for any help.

If it's useful to anyone,  [here is a link to a Geogebra file demonstrating the construction.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4PsefnS3F70R3pyYTl6QTRwMktET2pXbDJtb1BIY3dnZXhV/view?usp=sharing)  Since the picture is convoluted I figured sharing the file itself might be more helpful so that you can make parts of it disappear as you walk through the construction steps.

[EDIT: I decided to go ahead and manipulate things in my Geogebra construction and discovered that, actually, my construction did not construct a congruent triangle.]

Comment: Have you considered extending two sides through their common vertex, then arranging to draw a parallel to the third side so that the resulting new triangle is congruent to the one given?

Comment: @EricTowers I hadn't thought of that but now that you mention it I see exactly how to construct it that way.  If all else fails I'll ultimately go with that, thank you.  However, I think this may be against the "spirit" of the problem (I know, what the hell does that even mean?) because the construction wouldn't be done for a random other point.  I guess I feel that way because this proof requires showing that vertical angles are congruent, which I can do, but that lesson is supposed to come as a later exercise ... so it tells me maybe this proof method was not what's intended.

Comment: Same idea, but where the two triangles have a common side, leading to a parallelogram?